# $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(i) \neq i$

Tags: combinatorics

> If $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\rightarrow \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(i) \neq i$
>
> and $f(1)\neq 0,1,$ Then number of such functions are

Attempt: If $f(1)\neq 1,$ Then Using Dearrangement formula  we have

$\displaystyle 5!\bigg(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}\bigg)$

but don,t how to calculate all function which satisfy mention condition, could some help me Thanks

Comment: Do it the same way that the derangement formula is derived in the first place: inclusion-exclusion.  Have you seen a proof for the derangement formula?  It should be mentioned as well there is no additional requirement that $f$ be injective so the formula you use in the end will feel a bit different than the derangement formula.

Comment: Such $f$ are not always derangements, as $f$ need not be a bijection (as derangements are).

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1$ represent the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ where $f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=1$.

For each $i\in \{2,3,\dots,6\}$ let $X_i$ represent the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ where $f(i)=i$.

Let $X$ represent the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ with no additional requirements and use this as our universal set.

You are tasked with counting $|X_1^c\cap X_2^c\cap\dots \cap X_6^c|=|X\setminus (X_1\cup X_2\cup \dots\cup X_6)|=|X|-|X_1\cup X_2\cup\dots\cup X_6|$

Continue with inclusion exclusion, noting the symmetry between $X_2,\dots,X_6$ to more quickly expand the expression.

As for calculating each of the individual terms that result in the expansion, approach via multiplication principle.  For example, in calculating $|X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3|$, begin by choosing the value of $f(1)$ (*two choices*).  The values of $f(2)$ and $f(3)$ are forced to be $2$ and $3$ respectively.  Then choose the values for each of $f(4),f(5),f(6)$.  They each have seven choices respectively.  As such, $|X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3|=2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 7\cdot 7\cdot 7=2\cdot 7^3$